# How to retrieve and update specific values in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been working on the application where user is getting awarded by point for completing the challenge. For now user is getting awarded 10 points for each completed challenge. However I need to make it so that the user score would be updating each time user completes the challenge, in other words the points are pulled from database and added with extra points. (Points needs to be update where userID match userID)

How could I approach this problem, thanks for any suggestions.

```
public void stopActivity(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setTitle("Confirm");
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to stop?");

    builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            // Get the activity results
            String speedText = speedTxt.getText().toString();
            String distanceText = distanceTxt.getText().toString();
            String timeText = timeTxt.getText().toString();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your result is: " + "\n" + speedText + "\n" + distanceText + "\n" + timeText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //if the result is better
            if(Double.parseDouble(speed_challege) == Double.parseDouble(speedText) || Double.parseDouble(speed_challege) < Double.parseDouble(speedText) ){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You completed the challenge", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //award points if challenge is completed
                final DatabaseReference newResult = leaderBoard.push();
                String username = mCurrentUser.getEmail();

                //trim email leaving just username
                int index = username.indexOf('@');
                username = username.substring(0,index);

                newResult.child("UserName").setValue(username);
                newResult.child("uID").setValue(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                newResult.child("Score").setValue(score);
            }

            //if result is worse
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hard Luck Try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

[image]

Comment: what your leaderbord variable make reference on ?

Comment: DatabaseReference mRootRef = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference leaderBoard = mRootRef.child("Leaders");                      final DatabaseReference newResult = leaderBoard.push();

Answer (score 0):

Have you added java class which have **firebase context ** ? which is

```
 com.firebase.client.Firebase;
 import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
 import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;


public class `FirebaseContext` extends android.app.Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    enter code hereFirebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    if(!FirebaseApp.getApps(this).isEmpty()){
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No I have not ? Should I ?

Comment: Yes you have to add this class in order to connect with firebase, it actually provide firebase's context